# 7z directrories with unique passwords and filenames

Tags: bash, random, 7zip

I have a bunch of directories that I want to password protect with 7z. I want to generate a 64 character string to use as the password, a 6 character string to use as a prefix to the file.
I would ideally like to save both to a file in an array to keep track of the names and passwords.

Currently i do this manually, but I have too many to do now so I would like to use bash to do it.

I generated the passwords and 6 character string using my password manager. Copy and paste into the script and run it. For 1 or 2 files this ok, but now I have 100's.

```
Password_string=NzNeUGMpA1DkFPGQW3CEfLX1PIQdFNmKwyBrTqjv73ydcPwAJnNHUZFj4r2siBEu

a=1

for i in *;
do 7za a -t7z -m0=lzma -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=32m -ms=off -p$Password_string -mhe=on $i.7z $i
    new=$(printf "636995_archive_%04d.7z" "$a") #04 pad to length of 4
    mv -i -- "$i.7z" "$new" #rename to include numbers
    let a=a+1 #increment counter
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can randomly generate the prefix and password in your loop. After you create the archive, you can log the variables to a file before the next iteration of the loop.

Here's my example. I commented the `7z` command, so I could test the script and see the log.

```
seq=0
echo 'dir,prefix,seq,archive,password' > log.csv

for dir in /*; do
    prefix=$(head -c 6 <(tr -dc '0-9' < /dev/urandom))  # generate random 6-digit prefix
    pw64=$(head -c 64 <(tr -dc '[:alnum:]' < /dev/urandom))  # generate random 64-char alphanumeric string
    ((seq+=1))
    archive=$(printf "${prefix}_archive_%04d" "$seq")  # name of archive
    #7za a -t7z -m0=lzma -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=32m -ms=off -p"$pw64" -mhe=on "$archive.7z" "$dir"
    echo "$dir,$prefix,$seq,$archive,$pw64" >> log.csv
done
```

Partial view of the log:

```
dir,prefix,seq,archive,password
/bin,614175,1,614175_archive_0001,C7UhfDcfUyjV0JeOBykMn6fDMF4H4hWka7Y4xluzmWGDPqN0vlNzReIwLv7cYSE7
/boot,605074,2,605074_archive_0002,BsUQ5uEFpMZKZnKpUq7OH3VVMpp4jrsUrtVWBt6h1Q3S3mHAr5cnJk9w10LefzL0
/dev,676241,3,676241_archive_0003,5zcnV9EO8Z5nOA3VANGdMoVGTIdjT77RUKybd6cgfXLXDXLA9jiPYtJO66ZwTSbq
```

Comment: So maybe remove the  ```for dir in /*; do``` and replace it with ```for dir in *; do``` I got a bunch of permission denied because it tried to 7z my root directory.

Comment: Made a modification to find only directories, and to save the log.csv to a specific location. Outside of this it's excellent. Thanks for the help. In the future I'll set it up to use GPG keys to encrypt the directories.

Comment: @superuser-Miguel I should have been clearer about that. I used my root directory to test the script. Of course, you'll need to change that  for your purpose.

Comment: Why does adding a find command in the for loop produce 1 large file ? I changed ```for dir in $(find . -type d); do``` I had to change back to the original ```for dir in *; do```

Comment: To see what is happening run `find . -type d` from your starting directory. My guess is that `find` is returning subdirectories too. That is the default behavior of `find`. You probably need to add the option `-maxdepth` to prevent traversing subdirectories.